# How can i make OpenCart module self-installable?

Tags: opencart

I have created payment module in OpenCart.

In this there are 7 different files as below.

```
catalog/controller/payment/my_pay.php
catalog/model/payment/my_pay.php
catalog/language/english/payment/my_pay.php
catalog/view/theme/default/template/payment/my_pay.tpl
admin/controller/payment/my_pay.php
admin/language/english/payment/my_pay.php
admin/view/template/payment/my_pay.tpl
```

In order to install this module we need to place these files at appropriate locations.

I want these files/folder be placed  automatically at appropriate locations when i install module.

thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such an *automatization* in OpenCart (as e.g. in WordPress).

But if You have this folder/file structure:

```
catalog/
  |-controller/
    |-payment/
      |-my_pay.php
  |-model/
    |-payment/
      |-my_pay.php
  |-language/
    |-english/
      |-payment/
        |-my_pay.php
  |-view/
    |-theme/
      |-default/
        |-template/
          |-payment/
            |-my_pay.tpl
admin/
  |-controller/
    |-payment/
      |-my_pay.php
  |-language/
    |-english/
      |-payment/
        |-my_pay.php
  |-view/
    |-template/
      |-payment/
        |-my_pay.tpl
```

It is fairly enough to just copy these two main folders (`catalog` and `admin`) over the original ones... New files and/or folders will be created automaticaly (thanks to file system).